# the new line '\n' in android studio is displaying text in a enlarged way, i'll add the image here

Tags: android-studio

[image: Screenshot of display]

same happens with "break" statement. the text gets enlarged and is not even seen in the display.

...

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/nexttext"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
 android:paddingTop="32dp"
 android:layout_below="@id/intro"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:minLines="5"
 android:text="and i'll show you \n around this app"
 tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
  />
```

...

Comment: The link above says, "Don't trust the Visual editor. Your code does work in the emu."

Comment: yes i just saw on android emulator, it was displayed just how i wanted. thanks i wont trust the visual editor